# >> and / in python language

Tags: python, operator-keyword

In python language, is there any difference between '>>' operator and '/' operator in terms of execution time, when we are going to divide any Integer by multiple of '2' and why?

Comment: If it matters (hint: it doesn't), you're better off writing C.

Comment: If you care about the difference, don't use Python. Also, this is probably CPU-specific.

Comment: Actually i have just solved one spoj problem, in which there was a difference in execution time, so i was curious to know that it has same functionality as in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Python implementation has so incredibly much overhead that it is wrong language if you care about things like this. [These slides from Unladen Swallow presentation](http://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/downloads/detail?name=Unladen_Swallow_PyCon_2010.pdf&can=2&q=) are pretty illuminating...

As a matter of fact, the `>>` will be faster than `/`. But this is not from the cost of doing the division, but from the overhead of figuring out whether you are about to divide a float or an integer! If you instead divide by `//` (which assumes int), that will be as fast as the `>>`...

Comment: But according to the following analysis, '//' is slower that '>>' in python 2.7.`>>> timeit.timeit('a = 1000000000000000; a//2')
0.3532679080963135
>>> timeit.timeit('a = 1000000000000000; a>>1')
0.2281970977783203
`

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('a = 32; a / 2')
0.32588499376317426
>>> timeit.timeit('a = 32; a >> 1')
0.27532270162828
```

The reason seem to be obvious - operations on bits are faster.

Anyway, this difference is not a reason to use `>>` instead of `/` for division.

Comment: I don't think "operations on bytes are faster" explains it all.  Try comparing `a=32; a*2` and `a=32; a << 1`: at least for me, multiplication is *faster* than the bitshift.

Comment: @DSM I can't repro your results - left shift is faster that multiplication

Comment: For me, I get ~0.081 vs ~0.096 (2.7.2).  So clearly the operation execution time itself is subject to enough noise (compiler options? phase of moon?) that blanket statements will be difficult.

Answer (score 3):

`>>` only works on integers. The behavior of `/` depends on whether you're using 2.x or 3.x (or have imported `division` from `__future__`). So the important differences are *not* speed-related.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's almost certainly the case that the bit shift is faster when the types aren't known beforehand. But we may be able to be clever. Let's check:

```
In [11]: 2**20-37
Out[11]: 1048539

In [12]: timeit 1048539 >> 14
10000000 loops, best of 3: 29 ns per loop

In [13]: 2**14
Out[13]: 16384

In [14]: timeit 1048539 /16384
10000000 loops, best of 3: 72.2 ns per loop

In [15]: timeit 1048539 //16384
10000000 loops, best of 3: 29.1 ns per loop
```

Note the last case: if we specialise to integers with `//`, it's almost exactly the same!

Especially in Python, where the types aren't known beforehand, it's otherwise hard to optimise this sort of thing away. On the other hand, this means that `/` will work with non-integers, too -- which may be a bug or a feature, depending on what you're actually doing.